# How to catch an error with JSONP if the webservice returns a null result

Tags: jquery, error-handling, jsonp

I want to display an error when the data that is given by the URL does not exist. I've tried with the following code, but it is not working.

```
function getNum() {
    var num = document.getElementById('number').value;
    //alert(number);
    $('#shownum').empty();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.jsonp({
            url : 'http://localhost/json/num.php?&idnum='+num,
            callbackParameter : 'callback',
            success : function(data, status) {
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    var a = "";
                    var name = item.name;
                    var dob = item.dob;
                    var addr = item.addr;
                    b +='<br>' + name + '<br>';
                    b +=dob + '<br>';
                    b +=addr + '<br>';

                    $('#shownum').append(b);
                });
            },
            error : function() {
                $('#shownum').append('data not found');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

For example, if the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) returns `?(null);`, how do I append an error notification to `#shownum id`.

Comment: Where did `$.jsonp` come from? And, why is it needed?

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery Ajax documentation for the error callback:

> Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests.

You cannot catch errors with [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) requests using jQuery's native methods.

jQuery-JSONP seems to enable the error handling for all browsers other than [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29). I would suggest opening an issue on the project's [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) page if you are having problems with it.

Comment: i mean the errors if the given url return ?(null); as the result, how do i append an error message to #shownum

Comment: I don't understand. `console.log(arguments)` within your error handler, what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle this issue is adding success field to JSONP response. try like this:

```
{"success":false,"response":"data or objects"}
```

Your should handle your message.

The second way is to handle success event and check if response is 200 (which is success) or for example 404 (url does not exists).

```
success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
```

In case of problems with success, try this page: [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Again, the parameter you are interested in is textStatus.

Another possibility may be setting timeout to your ajax call: `timeout : 5000,`. After that you should handle error. Of course you can only guess why time out occurs.